how to install more_set_headers/more_clear_headers in nginx on windows
I want to remove my nginx server response header. On linux/unix, I am able to use more_set_headers in nginx.conf to do this. However, it’s not working on windows.
I’ve tried this:
http {
more_clear_headers 'Server';
server_tokens off; # Disable the server tokens
# Set a custom Server header value (empty string to remove it)
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;
client_max_body_size 100M;

but when I use more_clear_headers 'Server', I get this error:
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "more_clear_headers" in D:\nginx-1.26.1/conf/nginx.conf:14 nginx: configuration file D:\nginx-1.26.1/conf/nginx.conf test failed
How can I fix this please?
